# A CallableStatement function was executed and the out parameter 1 was of type java.sql.Types=2001 however type java.sql.Types=1111 was registered

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

I am trying to call a STORED PROCEDURE(with a out refcursor parameter) in postgresql through JPA2.1 like this:

```
public class JpaINParam {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        EntityManagerFactory emfactory = Persistence
                .createEntityManagerFactory("JPA2");
        EntityManager entitymanager = emfactory.createEntityManager();
        entitymanager.getTransaction().begin();


        StoredProcedureQuery q = entitymanager.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("get_hibernate_dtl");

        q.setParameter("modeval", "1");
        q.execute();

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Student> students = (List<Student>) q.getOutputParameterValue("resultset");

        for (Student student : students) {
            System.out.println(student.getFname());    
        }           

        entitymanager.getTransaction().commit();
        entitymanager.close();

        try {
            // storedProcedure.executeUpdate(); 
            System.out.println("444444444444");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }               
    }    
}
```

i get the following error:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
> ```
>
> 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
>       Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: A CallableStatement function was executed and the out parameter 1 was of
>   type java.sql.Types=2001 however type java.sql.Types=1111 was
>   registered.
>       Error Code: 0
>       Call: {?= CALL get_hibernate_dtl(?)}
>         bind => [2 parameters bound]
>       Query: ResultSetMappingQuery(name="get_hibernate_dtl" )
>         at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getDetailedException(QueryImpl.java:378)
>         at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:260)
>         at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.StoredProcedureQueryImpl.execute(StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java:316)
>         at com.javacodegeeks.examples.jpa.service.JpaINParam.main(JpaINParam.java:36)

the following is my entity class:

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name="get_hibernate_dtl", procedureName="get_hibernate_dtl", resultClasses={Student.class}, returnsResultSet = true, parameters={
        @StoredProcedureParameter(queryParameter="resultset", name="resultset", mode=ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR,type=Class.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(queryParameter="modeval", name="modeval", mode=ParameterMode.IN,type=String.class)


        })

@Entity
public class Student {
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
     private int sid;
     private String fname;
     private String lname;
     private String dept;
     private int year;
     private String email;

    public Student() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Student(int sid, String fname, String lname, String dept, int year,
            String email) {
        super();
        this.sid = sid;
        this.fname = fname;
        this.lname = lname;
        this.dept = dept;
        this.year = year;
        this.email = email;
    }



    public int getSid() {
        return sid;
    }

    public void setSid(int sid) {
        this.sid = sid;
    }

    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }

    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }

    public void setLname(String lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }

    public String getDept() {
        return dept;
    }

    public void setDept(String dept) {
        this.dept = dept;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }   

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [sid=" + sid + ", fname=" + fname + ", lname=" + lname
                + ", dept=" + dept + ", year=" + year + ", email=" + email
                + "]";
    }       
}
```

this is my procedure in postgresql:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dwh.get_hibernate_dtl(resultset OUT ahis_type.refcursor, modeval IN character varying DEFAULT '1'::character varying) AS
      query   VARCHAR2 (6000);
      v_type  NUMERIC(3,0);
      v_dwh_type_id VARCHAR2(100);

   BEGIN

         IF (modeval = 1) THEN

                QUERY := ' SELECT sid,fname FROM STUDENT ';

           END IF;           

        INSERT INTO tmp_table values ( 'get_hibernate_dtl----Modeval-->'||modeval||'query--->'||QUERY );

      OPEN resultset FOR QUERY;

   END
```

Comment: is there a different way of registering the ref cursor in postgresql? where is the problem ? any help is appreciated

Comment: Tighten up excessive line breaks

Comment: It is complaining about your out parameter.  Why have you specified "Class.class" as the type?  Examples all show using a void.class https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Release/2.5/JPA21#Ref_cursor_Example

Comment: i used void.class, Object.class types as well. but still gives the same error.